# MS Access Countdown Timer Update And Folder Trigger

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am quite new to VBA and MS Access so please bear with me.

I am looking for a countdown timer which is triggered every time a new file is added or created in a specific folder.

It should start at 7 minutes and run down to 0. If a new file has been added/created the timer should go back to 07:00 and redo the process.

My clock timer now only works manually:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command4_Click()
    Me.TimerInterval = 1000
    Me.Text2 = Me.Text0
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Timer()
    If Format(Me.Text2, "hh:nn:ss") = #12:00:00 AM# Then
        MsgBox "Time is up"
        Me.TimerInterval = 0
    Else
        Me.Text2 = DateAdd("s", -1, Me.Text2)
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks for reading and all the help in advance.

Comment: look at the `filesystemobject`

Comment: filesystemobject? @Nathan_Sav . Sorry I can't follow

Comment: Use google to find out about it   :)

Comment: Even though you can write code to combine your logic, a countdown timer and an file system event are two different things and technically they could both be the subject of a good question and can have two separate answers. Your code is not very clear since it contains no comments and uses names like "Text2", so it doesn't add much to the question.  It looks like you already understand something about the Access Form timers, so if your question is really about the file/folder triggers, you probably need to edit your question and reformulate what you're asking.

Comment: Also, FileSystemObject may help you to explicitly query files and folders, but it will not "trigger" anything to notify you that something has changed--it has no "events" that VBA can subscribe to.

Comment: If the file has been created the timer will reset, but what if it runs down to 0 but no file has been created?

Comment: @CPerkins Thanks for your response and yes, you're right. My question wasn't adressing the problem I was looking for. To clear things up I have to add few comments I guess. Text0 relates to the "Starttime"(which is typed in manually). Text2 simply just counts the time down I entered in Text0.

Comment: @KostasK.Hey and thanks also for your answer. I'll try out your code now. If the timer runs down to 0 it should provide a quick note that time is up and reset back to 7 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear to me what you're trying to achieve.

However you can start the timer on `Form_Load` and check every 5 seconds if the file exists until the 7 min cut-off point has been reached.

If the file was found, reset the timer or end it when it reaches 7 min.

```
Private Const max_ As Long = 420    '7 min/420 seconds
Private counter_ As Long            'Counter
Private file_ As String             'File to look for

'Load
Private Sub Form_Load()
    file_ = "YourFilePath"          'Use *.* for any file
    Me.TimerInterval = 5000         '5 seconds - change to whatever you like
End Sub

'Timer
Private Sub Form_Timer()
    If Len(Dir(file_)) = 0 Then
        'Nothing found
        If counter_ < max_ Then
            counter_ = counter_ + 5  'Keep counting - increment must match TimerInterval  
        Else
            Me.TimerInterval = 0     'End
            counter_ = 0
        End If
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'File found - do you action

    'Reset counter or End
    counter_ = 0
End Sub
```

**Note:**

Keep in mind as long as the file exists in the folder the timer will never stop.